# What is going on here with prototypes

Tags: javascript, prototype

So I have the following:

```
function A () { this.a = 0; }
function B () { this.b = 0; }
function C () {}

C.prototype = new B();

var c1 = new C();
var c2 = new C();

c1.b = 10;

console.log(c1.b); // 10 
console.log(c2.b); // 0
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mars6/2/

When I change `B.b` to an object, it seems to store the same object for each new `C`:

```
function A () { this.a = 0; }
function B () { this.b = new A(); }
function C () {}

C.prototype = new B();

var c1 = new C();
var c2 = new C();

c1.b.a = 10;

console.log(c1.b.a); // 10 
console.log(c2.b.a); // 10 - I want this to be 0
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mars6/1/

Can anyone explain what is going on/what the problem is.

Comment: Here is nice article that I think will explain the issue http://flippinawesome.org/2013/06/03/javascript-inheritance-how-to-shoot-yourself-in-the-foot-with-prototypes/

Comment: Maybe this is a better example to understand what happens: [http://jsfiddle.net/rdCgn/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/rdCgn/1/)

Answer (score 6):

When you did

```
C.prototype = new B();
```

You didn't say "whenever you need a prototype, do `new B`". What you said is "assign the prototype to `new B()` (which shouldn't be very surprising). What you get is:

```
C.prototype.b.a === 0
```

Whenever you do `new C`, you're not duplicating `C.prototype` - you're just linking to it, to the same `B` objcet:

```
C.prototype = new B()
   ^    ^
   |    |
  c1    c2

c1.b === c2.b; //true
```

As you may know, objects can be changed to your heart's content. So when you do `c1.b.a = 4`, you're going through to the underlying object and messing around with it.

Edit: The first example works because of how the property resolution works. The `b` property does not reside on the objects `c1` or `c2`. When you say "give me `c1.b`" the js engine does something like this:

1. Is there a `b` property on `c1`? Nope, there isn't.
2. Let's look at the prototype of `c1` (the actual prototype, what the object got its methods and properties from - in this case, `C.prototype`)
3. oh yes, it has a `b` property. Return it.

Which, in actual js, is this ([spec](http://es5.github.io/#x8.12.2)):

```
function GetProperty (name, obj) {
    while (obj !== null) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            return obj[name];
        }
        obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

So, in the case that `b` is an object, you've got a hold of an object. Changing it changes it like a normal object (do note that you're not assigning to `c1.b` directly - you'll see what I mean in a bit). Explained with arrows:

```
C.prototype.b = 0
   ^     ^
   |     |
  c1.b   c2.b
```

This is important, so I'll stress it again: When you get a hold on `c1.b`, you're getting an object, which is manipulated like any other object. Assigning properties to it is as any other normal object, and mutating it...well, mutates it.

Now, in the former case (`c1.b = 10`), you're actually *assigning* a property. This means you're creating a key/value pairing on the `c1` object itself. So, in the first step, we look to see if `c1` has a property `b` - and it has. Explained with more arrows:

```
      C.prototype.b = 0
            ^
            |
  c1.b=10  c2.b
```

Changing the latter example, we can observe the same effect:

```
//changing
c1.b.a = 10;
//to
c1.b = 4;

c2.b !== 4 && c2.b.a === 0; //true
```

To recap:

- In the former example, you simply set a property on the `c1` object.
- In the latter example, you set a property on an object on `c1`s prototype, which mutated it on all other `C` objects.

Comment: Does that explain the first case in my example, where I changed the underlying B and they were different?

Comment: @Ben In the first example, `C.prototype.b` wasn't an object, but a primitive value. When you accessed `b` in the latter example, you accessed it on `c1`s prototype link; in the former, you simply assigned it on the object. I'll edit my answer to explain this.

Comment: In the first case you set a value to the instance that replaces the prototype value only for this instance.

Comment: @Ben Edited. Hopefully it's clearer now.

Answer (score 3):

Here is whats happening as far as I know:

```
function A () { this.a = 0; }
function B () { this.b = 0; }
function C () {}

C.prototype = new B();

var c1 = new C();
var c2 = new C();

c1.b = 10;
```

When you write `c1.b = 10`, JavaSript will just add or change the local property `b` of the object `c1`. It doesn't care that the prototype already has a property `b` which in this case remains completely unaffected. Therefore:

```
console.log(c1.b); // 10  --> local property in c1
console.log(c2.b); // 0   --> prototype property
```

In your second example you are doing something different. Instead of assigning a property to `c1`, you are manipulating the prototype of it and thus affecting all instances together:

```
c1.b.a = 10;
```

`c1` doesn't have a property `b`, so it will take it from the prototype object and add or change ITS property `a`. Now neither `c1` nor `c2` have gained a local property and therefore both referring to the changed prototype:

```
console.log(c1.b.a); // 10  --> points to the prototype
console.log(c2.b.a); // 10 --> points to the prototype
```

**Possible Solution**

```
c1.b = new A();
c1.b.a = 10
```